# Random integer without a maximum range

Tags: python, random, integer

I was wondering how I can return a random integer with the range of 0 to infinity. Rather, I was wondering if it is even possible to do without crashing Python. Is there a way to do it with the randint() function or the randrange() function? I could not figure it out because both of these require a maximum range.

Comment: Use `sys.maxsize` as the upper limit?

Comment: It is not possible with a uniform distribution, because Python integers are unbounded (there is [no uniform distribution on a countable and infinite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255667/14118))

Comment: You cannot fit integers over a certain size in your computer. How many integers do you want? You have to divide your memory size by the number of integers you want (plus a little left over for everything else). Then you get your upper limit.

Comment: Just thinking about this mathematically without even considering language standards or physical resource constraints... A random number generator would *need* a lower and upper limit.  If the range really is from zero to infinity, then that means for any given possible number within that system there exists an *infinite* probability that the random number chosen will be larger.  So it's infinitely probable that any random number between zero and infinity will be infinity.  Your "random number generator" can just return "infinity" on every choice and still be correct.

Comment: @David reminds me of https://web.archive.org/web/20150123013256/http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @mkrieger1 I disagree with the stated closure reason. Answers given in the linked question focus on the outcome being uniform, which is not a stated requirement in this question. The [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is an integer valued distribution with infinite support. The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is another option.  While both are subject to practical limits for the magnitude of generated values based on machine hardware limitations, neither requires specification of an upper limit.

Comment: @pjs I felt similar, but this question would have to be edited to describe what non-uniform distributions (if any) are acceptable.

Comment: @wim If OP knew that, they probably wouldn't be asking the question. I think the existence of qualifying distributions would be of interest to them though. If nothing else, perhaps the comments will be of some help.

Comment: I don't see why this question should be reopened. The duplicate question does not seem to ask for a strictly *uniform* distribution either, as has been hinted at as a possible difference here in the comments. In order to be reopened, IMO this question should be edited to clearly define what requirements there are (other than the underspecified from 0 to infinity) and in a way that sets it apart from the other question. [from review]